# Json inside json with swift

Tags: json, swift

I have to read following json:

```
{
    lg = 1;
    "ribbon_count" =     {
        "t_r1" = 10;
        "t_r2" = 151;
        "t_r3" = 0;
        "t_r4" = 1;
    };
}
```

I am reading `lg` property with following lines:

```
let jsonResult: NSDictionary = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
let status=jsonResult["lg"] as! Int
```

But I don't know how to read `ribbon_count` property. How can I read the `t_r1`?

Comment: Did you try to read all of `ribbon_count`?

Comment: No because i dont know the type of ribbon_count. .... as! (what should i put here?)

Comment: I believe it is another `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use Swift collection types, they provide type information.
Second of all you probably don't need mutable containers.

```
let jsonResult = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
let status = jsonResult["lg"] as! Int
```

The value of `ribbon_count` is a dictionary with `String` keys and `Int` values

```
let ribbonCount = jsonResult["ribbon_count"] as! [String:Int]
let tR1 = ribbonCount["t_r1"]!
let tR2 = ribbonCount["t_r2"]!
let tR3 = ribbonCount["t_r3"]!
let tR4 = ribbonCount["t_r4"]!
```

Comment: What is mutable container?

Comment: Why do you pass the option although you have no idea what it does? `Mutable containers` are useful in Objective-C, you get a `NSMutableDictionary` and can change the objects in it. In Swift it's obsolete because Swift types declared with `var` are mutable by default. But if you only read the data in the dictionary you don't need `mutable containers` at all even in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for information, I tried your code but it is crashing without any error when i use jsonResult["ribbon_count"] as! [String:Int]

Comment: Then the values might be `String`. The dictionary string representation is ambiguous. Try `[String:String]`

Comment: Yep, it fixed now.